# Convert array with key values to only values - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have a below array

```
[
    0:"2015",
    1:"2016",
    2:"2017",
    3:"2018"
]
```

I need to remove the keys, so that it should look like

```
[
    "2015",
    "2016",
    "2017",
    "2018"
]
```

How to do this?

Comment: Use `Object.values`, btw your first array is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

**DEMO**

```js
let x = {
    0:"2015",
    1:"2016",
    2:"2017",
    3:"2018"
}

console.log(Object.values(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand the difference between "array" and "JSON".
Arrays can be defined as list of objects, for example `[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]`.

What you've created (`[0:"2015", 1:"2016", 2:"2017", 3:"2018"]`) does not adhere to JavaScript syntax.

You should be creating something as `{0:"2015", 1:"2016", 2:"2017", 3:"2018"}` which is a JSON object. After that, you can just use `Object.values()` function.

```js
const myObject = {
  0: "2015",
  1: "2016",
  2: "2017",
  3: "2018"
};
const val = Object.values(myObject);
console.log(val);
```